# WebRTC uses always TURN outside our LAN

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn, coturn

**My problem:**

I wrote a video chat application based on WebRTC. When two clients connect inside our LAN,
they always get a Peer-to-Peer connection. But when a client from our LAN connects with a
client outside our LAN it's always a Peer-to-TURN connection. When mobile devices connect
with each other it's often TURN-to-TURN.

**What I expect:**

I know of symmetric NAT problems and expect 20% to 30% of all connections to require a TURN connection. But so far
I never found any two clients outside of our LAN to get a Peer-to-Peer connection - that seems wrong.

**My setup:**

I tested on Chrome, Firefox, Electron, Android and iOS devices.

I use a *Coturn* server as STUN/TURN server. The server is accessible via internet.

I check via `peerConnection.getStats()` for an item with
`item.type === 'googCandidatePair' && item.googActiveConnection === 'true'` and look into its
`item.googLocalCandidateType` and `item.googRemoteCandidateType`. If the type is something like `relay`, its a TURN
connection.

**My analysis:**

When my system says the TURN server is involved and I stop *Coturn*, the video freezes - so I guess my applicatons
feedback is true.

I see `host`, `srflx` and `relay` ICE candidates on both sides. So the STUN/TURN config of my app seems correct.

I even built a test setup into my application, which tries to connect to a designated robot peer, with video and
audio disabled and try to send data via `peerConnection` data channel back and forth. Then I check the stats as stated
above, but it behaves the same: Peer-to-Peer in our LAN. Always TURN involved outside.

During my tests I found `peerConnection.oniceconnectionstatechange` to take a long time (ca. 12 sec) to change from
`connected` to `completed`. But again only with peers outside of LAN, not inside. However, the data channel opens
earlier and works. Waiting for `completed` before calling `getStats()` does not change my result. AFAIK only the
caller has a `completed` state.

**My hope:**

Has anyone any hints what I can change or how I can improve or extend my check? Which component might be the
issue (app code, network, STUN server, TURN server)?

Comment: Hey, that is exactly the behaviour I see on my WebRTC application. Every connection targeted to a peer outside my LAN results in a relay connection. Did you @Tsunamis find out any reason regarding your case in the meanwhile?

Comment: What I've also figured out is that jitsi (as a reference WebRTC application) is able to create a peer connection using a connection type other than relay (prflx, srflx) between my computer (LAN) and smartphone (mobile network). With my application it always results in a relay connection.

Comment: I am sorry, I never found a solution for this issue and am not working for the company any more.

Comment: OK. Thanks anyway. In the meanwhile I have found out that in my use cases connection type `relay` were detected correctly since both peers (computer and mobile phone) were participants of a network behind a symmetric NAT (here is a tool to identify the NAT type https://jsfiddle.net/5ftsd5c2/17/) where the source port is changing for each destination server. It somehow destroys my hope that WebRTC would establish a peer2peer connection in the most of the times.